# How to log network time breakup for API in nginx

Tags: android, google-chrome, networking, nginx

When I open a url in chrome I can find out breakup on network time for example:
Stalled time, DNS lookup time, Initial connection time, Request sending time, Waiting time (TTFB), Content download time.

Our API is also being used in Android and iOS app. 
It would be great to measure network breakup time from server. If not all the metrics, is it possible to measure some of the above mentioned metrics from server? I am using nginx server over php and mysql.

Or should I measure these metrics in each client (Android/iOS). If yes, is there any library for this purpose ?

Comment: Did you got any way to get the connection time breakup ?

Comment: Yes @VishalKardode I have added it as answer

Answer (score 0):

Some of these times line, DNS lookup time, Stalled times, initial connection time and Request sending time are present only in client. These are something that happens only in client, server does not know about these.
Server only knows about processing time and time taken to serve the content. Processing time can be easily calculated in script while execution by recording time when script started and time when script ended.
Time to serve can be calculated at websever, by recording time the request was alive.